# ASP.Net MVC Ajax.BeginForm OnComplete pass c# arguments in Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code in a MVC c# Razor view:

```
@{string url = "/Projects/_MonthRangesScriptsPartial";}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
  "_MonthRanges", 
  "Projects", 
  new { id = ViewBag.InputResourceID }, 
  new AjaxOptions { 
    HttpMethod = "POST", 
    UpdateTargetId = "MonthRanges", 
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnComplete = "updategraphArrayScript(@url,@ViewBag.InputResourceID)"
  }))
```

The code works almost perfectly, but I would like to resolve the c# variables to their values in the OnComplete line.

That is to say, the Razor engin should resolve the code to (for example):

```
<form action="/Projects/_MonthRanges/55" 
  data-ajax="true" data-ajax-complete="updategraphArrayScript(/Projects/assets,55)"
  ...>
```

Rather than:

```
<form action="/Projects/_MonthRanges/55" 
  data-ajax="true" data-ajax-complete="updategraphArrayScript(@url,@ViewBag.InputResourceID)"
  ...>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create another variable string:

```
@{
    string url = "/Projects/_MonthRangesScriptsPartial";
    string onComplete = String.Format("updategraphArrayScript({0}, {1})", url, ViewBag.InputResourceID);
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
  "_MonthRanges", 
  "Projects", 
  new { id = ViewBag.InputResourceID }, 
  new AjaxOptions { 
    HttpMethod = "POST", 
    UpdateTargetId = "MonthRanges", 
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnComplete = @onComplete
  }))
```

Comment: Exelent, and so elegant too. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for having to unaccept the solution: As the url is a string, I have to pass it in quote marks `string url = "\'/Projects/_MonthRangesScriptsPartial\'";` I can escape the quotemarks so that the String.Format does not replace them with `&#39;`, but then Ajax.BeginForm decides to replace them with `&#39` anyway. Double and tripple escaping don't seam to worth either - any ideas

Comment: But if you pass `onComplete` between quotes as indicated in my code, this should work...

Comment: If I pass it between quotes I end up with `data-ajax-complete="@onComplete"`. however I think this is realy a separate question about how razor deals with quote marks, so I will post in a new question

Answer (score 0):

Take off the @ when you assign your OnComplete value. You don't need it since you're already in the context of server side code.

`@` is used to switch html rendering context to server side code, and `<text></text>` is used to switch from server side context to html rendering. In example given above, you're already in the server side code context of the `BeginForm()` method so the @ is not needed. You're not writing the value of `onComplete` to the page, `BeginForm()` will handle all that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, even without the @, I still end up with `&#39`.