# Correctly using quote marks in MVC view Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having some difficulties using quote marks in ASP.Net Razer view as I keep ending up with them replaced with '

If I for example type:

```
@{string test = "String 'with' quotes"}
@test
```

I end up with:

```
String &#39;with&#39; quotes
```

In the above example this is desirable.

However, take this second example:

```
@{string myJSFunction = myJSFunction('myString')"}
@myJSFunction
```

I end up with:

```
myJSFunction(&#39;myString&#39;)
```

Which results in a broken javascript function.

I have tried excaping the quote marks with `\`, but they don't seem to be having any effect.

Here is the actual problem I am faced with:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
  "_MonthRanges", 
  "Projects", 
  new { id = ViewBag.InputResourceID }, 
  new AjaxOptions { 
      HttpMethod = "POST", 
      UpdateTargetId = "MonthRanges", 
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
      OnComplete = @myJSFunction
}))
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your issue is already mentioned (Html.Raw()) but I'm not sure why you're using @ in your code sample given. From the looks of it you're already in code block when you try to assign it, so why use the razor.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
  "_MonthRanges", 
  "Projects", 
  new { id = ViewBag.InputResourceID }, 
  new AjaxOptions { 
      HttpMethod = "POST", 
      UpdateTargetId = "MonthRanges", 
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
      OnComplete = @myJSFunction
}))
```

should be

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
  "_MonthRanges", 
  "Projects", 
  new { id = ViewBag.InputResourceID }, 
  new AjaxOptions { 
      HttpMethod = "POST", 
      UpdateTargetId = "MonthRanges", 
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
      OnComplete = myJSFunction
}))
```

@ is what tells the StreamWriter for the page to write the result to the response, and as such is intended to be injected into the page after HtmlEncoding. Using Html.Raw bypasses the Html encoding aspect but in your case you're not writing it the page directly yourself, you're letting `Html.BeginForm` handle that, so you don't need the @ in the assignment of your `OnComplete` function.

**UPDATE:** Ok, another thing I forgot to mention is that the methods passed to the AjaxOptions are Javascript functions only, no parameters by the looks of it. Parameters are passed in automatically by the Unobtrusive scripts that handle all the wiring. So your form should look like this...

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
  "_MonthRanges", 
  "Projects", 
  new { id = ViewBag.InputResourceID }, 
  new AjaxOptions { 
      HttpMethod = "POST", 
      UpdateTargetId = "MonthRanges", 
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
      OnComplete = "myJSFunction"
}))
```

And it will handle the rest. If you need to pass additional parameters in the `myJSFunction` function, you're probably going to have to expose them via other means. Either as a javascript variable or by associating it with some other element and access it using `$("elementselector").data("dataAttributeName")` (this is my preferred and suggested method). One of the common requested modifications made to the unobtrusive ajax JavaScript libraries (I wish Microsoft would just adopt this change and be done with it) is to set the context of `this` to the element that triggered the ajax event. So for in this case it would make `this` equal to the form element. With all this in mind, here's my recommendation.

*First:*
Modify your Unobtrusive Ajax script file so that the source element gets assigned to the `this` keyword  so that's it's available in your JavaScript handling the unobtrusive events.
[This question outlines what it involves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655280/get-calling-form-in-onsuccess/14655719#14655719) (one line added to the file)

*Second:*
Add your string to one of the data attributes on your form

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "_MonthRanges",
    "Projects",
    new {id = ViewBag.InputResourceID},
    new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            UpdateTargetId = "MonthRanges",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,

            OnComplete = "myJSFunction"
        },
    new { data_parameter_name = "myString" }))
```

*Third:*
Access your parameter from inside of the javascriptfunction handling your event.

```
<script>
    function myJSFunction(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        //data, textStatus and jqXHR are set for you by the unobtrusive ajax script file automatically, feel free to use them
        var parameter = $(this).data("parameterName");
        alert(parameter);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You seem to be correct in saying that the @ is not necessary, however, I still end up with the `&#39` =(

Comment: Now you got me curios as to what's going on here. I'm gonn setup a page just like this and see what the deal is...

Comment: K, I've updated my answer with my suggestion, give that a shot.

Answer (score 2):

In razor, `@` will encode and render. Try [`Html.Raw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method. This method returns markup that is not HTML encoded.

```
@Html.Raw(myJSFunction)
```

So if you want to execute the function in a script block, you can do it like

```
@{string myJSFunction = "alert('Rise and Shine')";}
<script type="text/javascript">  
    @Html.Raw(myJSFunction)
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `@` operator always HTML-encodes strings. If you want the raw string value, use `@Html.Raw(myJSFunction)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. However this does not seem to work in my scenario: I need to set the `onComplete` parameter of Ajax.BeginForm to `myJSFunction` `OnComplete = Html.Raw(myJSFunction)`

Comment: @Chopo87: Why you are then assigning to a variable. Directly mention the function name there.

Comment: Because I actualy have to resolve some other variables into parameters and can't seem to do it in line. see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947755/asp-net-mvc-ajax-beginform-oncomplete-pass-c-sharp-arguments-in-razor-view/15947878#15947878

Comment: @Chopo87 Should be `OnComplete = @Html.Raw(myJSFunction)`